# Documenting and allowing for macro function on Javascript Class

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I'm trying to write a typescript definition for the [Collectionsjs](https://github.com/logaretm/collectionsjs) node module. So far it's going fine the only thing I am unsure about is that the module comes with a ["macro" function](https://logaretm.github.io/collectionsjs/file/src/collection.js.html#lineNumber674) on it that allows you to create new functions on the class by assigning them to "prototype".

Is it possible to document this kind of thing in typescript or at least allow it to work in the way you might expect?

Here is my definition:

```
static macro(name: string, callback: (coll: Collection<unknown>, ...args: unknown[]) => unknown): void;
```

Thanks

Comment: Functions that modify prototypes should not be used and die.

Answer (score 0):

So I asked this question on the repo I was trying to merge with. The answer being that it isn't really possible. You can find the discussion on the github merge request [here](http://%20https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/pull/33592#issuecomment-469902574)